# Squeez the words in c - Basic C Language

Tags: c

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in the following code,

That is what I want to achieve

> **User Input:** aaaaaadsssssc
>
> **Output:** a6ds5c

My program was working fine until this morning I was being stupid enough to overwrite the whole file. Oh well, welcome to Linux! Since I rewrite the program it is giving me **Segment Fault Error**, and I have no clue what I am doing wrong here and my mind is stop working at this point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
        int i, j, k, count;
        char str[1000];

        printf("Enter: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", str);
        printf("You have typed: %s\n", str);

        printf("length: %d\n", strlen(str));
        for (i = 1; i < strlen(str); i++){
                count = 2;

                if (str[i] == str[i-1]){
                        j = i;
                        while (str[i] == str[i+1]){
                                if (k != strlen(str)){str[k] = str[k+1];}
                                else{str[k] = '\0';}
                                i++; k++; count++;
                        }
                str[j] = count;
                k++;
                }
        }
        str[k] = '\0';
        printf("output: %s\n", str);
}
```

I have this due in few days and I screwed up so bad. Could someone please point out the mistake I am making? A big thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't initialized `k`. What are you expecting its value to be when you compare it with `strlen(str)` in the innermost loop?

Comment: Unrelated to the segfault, but I suggest using `%zu` instead of `%d` to print the `size_t` returned by `strlen()`.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I did initialized `k`, I think I don't need to compare `k` with `strlen(str)` because `k` will never be equals to `strlen(str)`. Just to be on a safe side I decided to add `NULL` character to avoid having garbage values in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(){
            int i, count;
            char str[1000];

            printf("Enter: ");
            scanf("%s", str);
            printf("You have typed: %s\n", str);

            //used strlen() only once because strlen() takes O(n) time
            int len = strlen(str);
            printf("length: %d\n", len);

            //iterate through the string
            for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++){

                    //every char appears at least once
                    count = 1;

                    //print the char regardless of it repeating
                    printf("%c", str[i]);
                    for (int j = i; str[j] == str[j+1]; ++j, ++i)
                            ++count;

                    //print the count if it's greater than 1
                    if (count > 1) printf("%d", count);
            }

            //print the last char if it's different from the second last
            if (str[len - 1] != str[len - 2]) printf("%c", str[len - 1]);

            //print new line
            printf("\n");
    }
```